# PowerShell Output to text

Tags: powershell

I have the below PowerShell script to check if a file is locked - how do I also output the 0 or 999 to a text file, for example C:\stuff\PSOutput.txt?

```
$file = "\\xxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxxx\test.log"
try {
    [IO.File]::OpenWrite($file).Close();
    exit 0
} catch {
    exit 999
}
$exit | Out-File -FilePath "C:\stuff\PSOutput.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't `exit` the script. Save your exit value into a variable and write it to a file.

```
$file = "\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxxx\test.log"
try { [IO.File]::OpenWrite($file).close(); $exit = 0 } catch { $exit = 999}
$exit | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Path\to\myFile.txt"
```

`exit` stops your script and returns your exit value. To do more stuff with your script (like saving the value into a file), you should not use exit.

Comment: This doesn't work I'm afraid.  It doesn't create the txt file.  I then created a blank txt file and it doesn't write to it.

Comment: nothing - the script still executes.  I have full read\write access to the folder in question.

Comment: Have a look at my second line of code and yours. It's different. Yours: `exit 0`, mine: `$exit = 0` and the same with `exit 999` compared to `$exit = 999`

Comment: Still doesn't work I'm afraid.  I'm calling this via a Process Task in SSIS.  Its ok though, I'm just going to use the logging from within SSIS.  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit the path for your file in first line of script:

```
$fileName = "test.txt"                                                           
$file = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo -ArgumentList $fileName
[System.IO.FileStream] $fs = $file.OpenWrite(); 
if (!$?) {
"0" | Out-File "C:\PSOutput.txt"
}
else {
$fs.Dispose()
"999" | Out-File "C:\PSOutput.txt"
}
```

Comment: This script forms part of a SSIS package - will the 0 or 999 still be fed back to SSIS in the above example?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with SSIS packages, if those are XML, and are already generated, you can try to Append the file, with:
"0" Out-File -Encoding Ascii -append "C:\PSOutput.txt"
But remember that Append adds to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$file = "\\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxxx\test.log"
$exitCode = 0
if (Test-Path -Path $file -PathType Leaf) {
    $fileInfo = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $file
    try {
        $stream = $fileInfo.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, [System.IO.FileShare]::None)
        if ($stream) { $stream.Close() }
    } 
    catch {
        $exitCode = 999  # the file is locked by a process.
    }
}
$exitCode | Out-File -FilePath "C:\stuff\PSOutput.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `exit` statements in your code cause your script to exit before it gets to the point where `$exit` would be written to the output file. But even if it got there it wouldn't actually record the exit code, because the `exit` keyword doesn't magically fill the (undefined) variable `$exit` with the exit code. You may be confusing it with the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) `$LastExitCode`, which gets updated on the *caller* side after the callee exited.

What you actually want to do is define a custom function that properly sets the exit code and does everything else you want to do before actually exiting:

```
function ExitWithCode($exitcode) {
    $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
    $exit | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\stuff\PSOutput.txt'
    exit $exitcode
}
```

then use it in your code like this:

```
try {
    [IO.File]::OpenWrite($file).Close()
    ExitWithCode 0
} catch {
    ExitWithCode 999
}
```

Using `$host.SetShouldExit()` in addition to `exit` ensures that your script always sets the proper exit code, [regardless of how it's invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50202663/1630171).