# How to prevent exit of host and return exit code?

Tags: powershell, exit-code

Ansgar Wiechers' answer works well whenever starting a new PowerShell process. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50202663/447901 This works in both cmd.exe and powershell.exe.

```
C:>type .\exit1.ps1
function ExitWithCode($exitcode) {
  $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
  exit $exitcode
}
ExitWithCode 23
```

In a cmd.exe interactive shell.

```
C:>powershell -NoProfile -Command .\exit1.ps1
C:>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
23
C:>powershell -NoProfile -File .\exit1.ps1
C:>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
23
```

In a PowerShell interactive shell.

```
PS C:>powershell -NoProfile -Command .\exit1.ps1
PS C:>$LASTEXITCODE
23
PS C:>powershell -NoProfile -File .\exit1.ps1
PS C:>$LASTEXITCODE
23
```

HOWEVER... Running the .ps1 script inside an existing interactive PowerShell host will exit the host completely.

```
PS C:>.\exit1.ps1
    <<<poof! gone! outahere!>>>
```

How can I prevent it from exiting the host shell?

Comment: Patient: Doctor, it hurts when I do "this".  Doctor: Then don't *DO* "this"!!  You are asking "How can I get the light to not turn off when I turn it off?".  :)  The `exit` command will exit the current command parser.  If the host program you are running is at the top level, the `exit` command will close that parser, leaving nothing else left open.  I believe the answer is if you don't want it to exit, stop telling it to exit?

Comment: Customer: I brought this car back because it cannot make a right turn. Sales: Then don't make any right turns!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do not use [`$host.SetShouldExit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshost.setshouldexit)**: it is not meant to be called by user code.
Instead, it is used *internally* by PowerShell *in response to an `exit` statement in user code*.

**Simply use `exit 23`** directly in your `exit1.ps1` script, which will do what you want:

- When run **inside a PowerShell session**, the script will set exit code `23` without exiting the PowerShell process as a whole; use `$LASTEXITCODE` to query it afterwards.

  ```
    .\exit.ps1; $LASTEXITCODE # -> 23
  ```
- When run **via the [PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)**:
- with **`-File`**, the exit code set by the script automatically becomes the PowerShell process' exit code, which the caller can examine; when called from `cmd.exe`, `%ERRORLEVEL%` reflects that exit code.

  ```
       powershell -File .\exit.ps1
       :: This outputs 23
       echo %ERRORLEVEL%
  ```
- with **`-Command`**, *additional work* is needed, because PowerShell then simply **maps any nonzero exit code to `1`**, which causes the specific exit code to be lost; to compensate for that, simply **execute `exit $LASTEXITCODE` as the last statement**:

  ```
       powershell -Command '.\exit.ps1; exit $LASTEXITCODE'
       :: This outputs 23
       echo %ERRORLEVEL%
  ```

For **more information about how PowerShell sets exit codes**, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375).

---

**If**:

- you do not control how your script is invoked via the CLI, yet must *ensure that the correct exit code is reported even when the script is invoked via `-Command`*,
- *and* you're willing to assume the risk of using `$host.SetShouldExit()`, even though it isn't designed for direct use,

you can try the following:

```
function ExitWithCode($exitcode) {
  if ([Environment]::CommandLine -match ( # Called via the CLI? (-File or -Command)
    ' .*?\b' + 
    [regex]::Escape([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($PSCommandPath)) +
    '(?:\.ps1\b| |$)')
  ) {
    # CAVEAT: While this sets the exit code as desired even with -Command,
    #         the process terminates instantly.
    $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
  }
  else {
    # Exit normally, which in interactive session exits the script only.
    exit $exitcode
  }
}

ExitWithCode 23
```

The **function looks for the file name of the executing script on the process command line to detect whether the enclosing script is being invoked directly via the CLI**, via the automatic `$PSCommandPath` variable, which contains the script's full path.

If so, the `$host.SetShouldExit()` call is applied to ensure that the exit code is set as intended even in the case of invocation via `-Command`.
Note that this amounts to a *repurposing* of the effectively *internal* `.SetShouldExit()` method.
Surprisingly, this repurposing works even if additional commands come after the script call inside the `-Command` string, but note that this invariably means that the success status of the truly last command - if it isn't the script call - is then effectively ignored.

This **approach isn't foolproof**<sup>[1]</sup>,but **probably works well enough in practice.**

---

<sup>[1]</sup>

- There could be *false positives*, given that only the file *name* is looked for, without extension (because `-Command` allows omitting the `.ps1` extension of scripts being called).
- There could be *false negatives*, if the script is being called via another script or via an alias.

Comment: Thanks!. Here are few things I've learnt from trial and error: 1. `PowerShell_ISE.exe` 10.0.19041.1 will always return exit code 1 or 0 - no matter if I use `-File` or `-Command`, while `VS Code` 1.60.2 works well. 2. if I write both `return X` and `exit X` - the return will mess-up the exit code.

Comment: @itsho, I don't see that behavior in the ISE with `-File`, and I generally wouldn't expect the host environment to make a difference. Note that `return` is for returning _data_, not _exit codes_. For more information on exit codes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375). For information on `return` vs. `exit`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67642758/45375).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I prevent it from exiting the host shell?

You can check if the currently running PowerShell process is a child of another PowerShell parent process, and only call `$host.SetShouldExit()` when that condition is true.  For example:

```
function ExitWithCode($exitcode) {
   # Only exit this host process if it's a child of another PowerShell parent process...
   $parentPID = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId=$PID" | Select-Object -Property ParentProcessId).ParentProcessId
   $parentProcName = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId=$parentPID" | Select-Object -Property Name).Name
   if ('powershell.exe' -eq $parentProcName) { $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode) }

   exit $exitcode
}
ExitWithCode 23
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is looking good. It still does not work for cmd.exe when using `-Command`, but that is probably not a good use anyway. I am guessing that it will need to be `if ('powershell.exe', 'pwsh.exe' -contains $parentProcName)` for future versions.