# Why won't the "Exit" function work in my PowerShell code?

Tags: powershell

When I try the "Exit" function. It does not close the console. It doesn't do anything. How can I change it to make it exit the console?

```
Write-Host "-------------- MENU ---------------"
Write-Host "Utility Menu"
Write-Host "1 = Help Ipconfig"
Write-Host "2 = Ipconfig"
Write-Host "3 = Notepad"
Write-Host "4 = Calculator"
Write-Host "5 = Exit"
Write-Host "-----------------------------------"

$userinput = Read-Host "Please select a menu item: "

switch ( $userinput )
{
  1 {Help Ipconfig}
  2 {ipconfig}
  3 {start notepad}
  4 {start calc.exe}
  5 {Exit}
}
```

Comment: EXIT closes the window, but only when the window was opened by the action that started the script, for example, right-clicking a script and selecting "run with powershell". I suspect you opened an interactive console and started the script by typing its full name. In this case the EXIT keyword will not close the console window (that would be a nuisance).

Comment: Try `[System.Environment]::Exit(0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing from my comment...

Gif of your code and menu selection

[image: Execution]

Running your code a straight script will do nothing on the exit option. Refactoring your script as a function does work.

```
# Saved as Start-Menu.ps1
Function Start-Menu {
    Clear-Host

    Write-Host "-------------- MENU ---------------"
    Write-Host "Utility Menu"
    Write-Host "1 = Help Ipconfig"
    Write-Host "2 = Ipconfig"
    Write-Host "3 = Notepad"
    Write-Host "4 = Calculator"
    Write-Host "5 = Exit"
    Write-Host "-----------------------------------"

    $userinput = Read-Host "Please select a menu item: "

    switch ( $userinput )
    {
      1 {Help Ipconfig}
      2 {ipconfig}
      3 {start notepad}
      4 {start calc.exe}
      5 {Exit}
    }
}
```

Another gif on the action.

[image: Using a function]

Or use what Colyn1337, gave you or this...

```
    switch ( $userinput )
    {
      1 {Help Ipconfig}
      2 {ipconfig}
      3 {start notepad}
      4 {start calc.exe}
      5 {Stop-Process -Id $PID}
    }
```

...(which gets the current process ID of the PowerShell session) and thus no need for the function and just run the script as-is, and note though the namespace is slower to close than the function or $PID approach.

[image: Using .Net Namespace]

Comment: Most elegant answer I've seen!  How did you gif all the screen action like that???

Comment: Thanks 'adamt8'. As for the Giffing thing, I use a tool called [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/downloads) for years to do that and all my repro or lab demos when I teach classes. Formally I used another tool called 'Demomate', to do 'click-thru' demos/labs, but it is no longer made/released, though the company that developed it is still around.

Answer (score 6):

There is helpful information in the existing answers, but I feel that *conceptual framing* is called for:

> `exit` [...] It does not close the console.

**It is unusual for a *script* to want to terminate *the entire interactive PowerShell session*** (which is what would lead to the console window closing), and **`exit` would only do so *outside a script*** - see the bottom section for details.

If exiting the session as a whole from a script or function<sup>[1]</sup> is really your intent, use [`[Environment]::Exit(0)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.Exit), as suggested by [Colyn1337](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2679666/colyn1337). (`0` is the exit code to report on process termination, which by convention signals success; when closing an interactive session, this exit code is likely irrelevant.)

---

#### Background information

**[Language keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Keywords) for exiting various scopes from PowerShell**:

- **`break`** is used to exit *just* a **`switch`** statement or a ***loop* statement (`foreach` / `for`, `while`, `do`)**; that is, execution continues in the same scope *after* such a statement - see the conceptual [about_Break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Break) help topic.

  - **Pitfall**: If you use `break` or `continue` *without* an enclosing loop or `switch` statement, PowerShell looks up the call stack for such a statement and exits the first such statement it finds; if there is none, the current call stack is terminated; that is, at the very least the enclosing script terminates as a whole.

    - Note that **a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call** (whose built-in aliases are `%` and, somewhat confusingly, `foreach`), invariably in a *pipeline*, is ***not* a loop**; to "break" out of a script block passed to `ForEach-Object`, i.e. to move on to the next pipeline input object, **use `return`**.
- **`return`** is used to exit an **enclosing *script file* (if executed directly in the script file's top-level scope) or *function* or [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`)**, optionally by first outputting *data* via an expression or command passed as an *argument* (e.g. `return 'foo'`); see the conceptual [about_Return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Return) help topic.

  - `return` has *no* effect on the *exit code* reported by a script and therefore potentially by a PowerShell process as a whole; only `exit` can be used to set the exit code - see below.
- **[`exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Keywords#exit)** is used to **exit an *interactive session* or the *enclosing script file*** and to optionally set an *exit code*:

  - *Outside* of a script file, `exit` exits an interactive PowerShell session *as a whole* (closes the console window).
  - *Inside* of a script file, `exit` always exits that script (only) - even when called from a *function* inside that script.

    - Note the contrast with `return`, which from a function just exits that function, whether called from inside a script or not.
  - `exit $exitCode` - where `$exitCode` stands for any *integer*<sup>[2]</sup> - can be used to **set a script / session's *exit code***; using **just `exit` is the same as `exit 0`**:

    - Since PowerShell's [error handling](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583) *isn't* based on exit codes (unlike that of shells such as `cmd.exe` and `bash`), setting an exit code is **primarily of interest for communicating success vs. failure to *outside callers***.
    - If you execute a script from the outside via PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh) (e.g., `pwsh -File script.ps1`), the exit code set via `exit $exitCode` will also become the *process* exit code, which the outside caller - e.g., a CI tool - can then inspect.

      - Session-internally, an exit code set by a script via `exit $exitCode` is reflected in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode), though note that this variable is also set by any call to an *external program*, to that program's process exit code.
    - See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375) for more information about the relevance and use of exit codes in PowerShell.

---

<sup>[1] As [postanote's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67597380/45375) shows, `exit` from inside a *function* that has been *dot-sourced (loaded directly into) the global scope*, exits the whole session too. However, it is better to explicitly signal the unusual intent to exit the *entire session* via `[Environment]::Exit(0)`.</sup>

<sup>[2] Technically, you can pass *any* expression or command to `exit` (as with `return`, though the expression/command's output becomes *data* there, as-is), but **anything that cannot at least be *converted* to an integer - e.g., `exit 'not a number'` - is *quietly ignored*** and is the **same as `exit 0`**. Also note that **the *range* of valid integers varies by platform**: *Windows* supports `[int]` values, i.e. signed 32-bit values that include *negative* numbers. By contrast, Unix-like platforms only support unsigned `[byte]` values, i.e. numbers from `0` to `255` (negative numbers are converted to positive ones, and only the lowest byte is considered for larger values ).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The `Exit` command is really like a function within the powershell parser.  There's some packaging around it and when it executes, `Exit` doesn't always mean `Exit`.  It quite often will be replaced by the parser with a `Return`.

To get around that, you can instruct the runtime to terminate with the following code:

`[System.Environment]::Exit(0)`

The integer in the Exit method is the return code you want the runtime to out as it exits.  Typically anything other than 0 will be interpreted as an error.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution from your comment as an answer; +1 for an effective solution, but the framing of the `exit` _language keyword_ isn't quite correct (see my answer for details).

Answer (score 0):

Use *break* instead of *exit*.

```
Write-Host "-------------- MENU ---------------"
Write-Host "Utility Menu"
Write-Host "1 = Help Ipconfig"
Write-Host "2 = Ipconfig"
Write-Host "3 = Notepad"
Write-Host "4 = Calculator"
Write-Host "5 = Exit"
Write-Host "-----------------------------------"

$userinput = Read-Host "Please select a menu item: "

switch ( $userinput )
{
  1 {Help Ipconfig}
  2 {ipconfig}
  3 {start notepad}
  4 {start calc.exe}
  5 {break}
}
```

Comment: `break` is the right statement for exiting the `switch` statement, but the OP is looking to close the current console window, i.e. _exit the current (PowerShell) process_.