# Using Exit versus Break to Completely Finish Script Run

Tags: powershell

On Saturday and Sunday the file may not be created which this script scans for its pattern match - where should I place a test if the file exists -before the While Loop or inside it?  It runs great when the file exists - but on the Saturday run - it didn't exit and was still running Monday morning.

```
If(!( Test-Path -Path $Directory\$Source)) {exit or break?}
```

HEREs the current code ---

````
$job = Start-Job {
    # Note: $file should be the absolute path of your file
    Get-Content $File -Raw | Select-string -Pattern "Idle" -Quiet
}

while($true)
{
    # if the job has completed
    if($job.State -eq 'Completed')
    {
        $result = $job|Receive-Job

        # if result is True
        if($result)
        {
            $elapsedTime.Stop()
            $duration = $elapsedTime.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
            
            # .... send email logic here
            # for success result

            break #=> This is important, don't remove it
        }

        # we don't need a else here,
        # if we are here is because $result is false
        
        $elapsedTime.Stop()
        $duration = $elapsedTime.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")

        # .... send email logic here
        # for unsuccessful result
        
        break #=> This is important, don't remove it
    }

    # if this is running for more than
    # 60 minutes break the loop
    if($elapsedTime.Elapsed.Minutes -ge 60)
    {
        $elapsedTime.Stop()
        $duration = $elapsedTime.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
        
        # .... send email logic here
        # for script running longer 
        # than 60 minutes

        break #=> This is important, don't remove it
    }
    
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}

Get-Job|Remove-Job ```
````

Comment: `break` exits out of script blocks and functions. Sure it will work in files if you are not nested in anything but if you want to *exit a file* use exit but if you instead want to *return something* from a file or are using a file like a function (which might I add, you can just use a function in here and import it then call the function) you could theoretically use `break` or `return` but that would be unorthodox.

Comment: It is not entirely clear, what "the file" is: you have a `Get-Content` with `$File`, and nowhere else after it you have any paths. So if the `Test-Path` has anything to do with `$File$`, then it should be before `Get-Content`.

Comment: Good advice to use `exit`, @NicoNekoru, but the framing of `break` isn't quite correct; please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

- To **exit a *script*** as a whole (even from a function *inside* a script), **use `exit`**.

  - If you use `exit` *outside* a script:

    - An *interactive* session is terminated as a whole.
    - `exit` inside a *job*'s script block (started with [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) or [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)) terminates that job (though its prior output, if any, can still be retrieved with [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job)).
  - To exit just a *function*, use `return`.
- **`break` and `continue` should only ever used to break out of *loops*** (`foreach` / `for`, `while`, `do`) and **`switch` statements**.

  - **Pitfall**: If you use `break` or `continue` *without* an enclosing loop or `switch` statement, PowerShell looks up the call stack for such a statement and exits the first such statement it finds; if there is none, the current call stack is terminated. That is, at the very least the enclosing script terminates.
    That is, `break` can *situationally, accidentally* act like `exit` (without the ability to specify an exit code), but you should never rely on that.

See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67642758/45375) for more information.

Comment: can you `break` out of functions?

Comment: @NicoNekoru, no: only `return` should be used to exit _functions_. `break` would again go looking up the call stack for an enclosing loop and terminate the script as a a whole if none is found.