# How to catch errors from BitsTransfer module

Tags: powershell, error-handling, microsoft-bits

I want to catch errors from BitsTransfer module, download link or destination not found, not accessible, required credential etc. How can I do this?

Here is the code:

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer

Try {
    $Source = ""
    Start-BitsTransfer -Source $Source -Destination "" -Priority Foreground -ErrorAction Stop
} Catch [System.Exception] {
    Write-Warning "Oopsie daisy, an error popped up out of the blue!"
    Break
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **inspect the details of a PowerShell error (exception)**, use the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) in the `catch` block of your [`try` / `catch` / `finally` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally).

In this context, `$_` refers to an instance of [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord), the type used to represent PowerShell errors.

You're free to access the properties of this type, but a simple way to visualize the error *message* is to simply *stringify* the error record (either inside `"..."`, e.g.`"$_"`, or by calling `.ToString()`).

Here's a simplified example:

```bash
try { 
  1 / 0  # Provoke a (statement-)terminating error
}
catch {
  # -> 'Error message: Attempted to divide by zero.'
  "Error message: $_"
}
```

If (presumably just for debugging) you want a nicely formatted representation of the error record, pipe it to [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list) with the `-Force` switch:

```bash
try { 
  1 / 0 
}
catch {
  # Print the properties of the error record to the display.
  $_ | Format-List -Force
}
```

In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** you can get an even more detailed for-display representation using the [`Get-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-error) cmdlet:

```bash
try { 
  1 / 0 
}
catch {
  # Print a detailed representation of the error recorddisplay.
  $_ | Get-Error
}
```

Note:

- By default, PowerShell collects all errors that occur in the session in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error), in reverse order (most recent first, i.e. `$Error[0]`).
- You may also collect *non*-terminating<sup>[1]</sup>  errors that occur on a *per-call basis* by using the [common `-ErrorVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-errorvariable), which is supported by cmdlets and [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) scripts/functions.
- The **inspection techniques above can equally applied to elements of the `$Error` collection or variable containing error records collected via `-ErrorVariable`**; a simple example:

  ```bash
  # Ignore the error - it is still collected in $Error, howevever.
  try { 1 / 0 } catch { } 

  # Inspect the error via $Error
  $Error[0] | Format-List -Force
  ```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `Catch [System.Exception]`

While you *can* constrain `catch` handlers by the type of the .NET exception that the error record wraps, doing so is rare in practice, and there's never a good reason to constrain by `[System.Exception]`, as *any* error will match it; in other words: it is redundant.

> `Break`

Only ever use `break` and `continue` inside `switch` and loop statements (`while`, `do`, `for`, `foreach`). Otherwise, PowerShell looks up the call stack for such a statement and exits the first one it finds; if there is none, the current call stack is terminated; that is, at the very least the enclosing script terminates as a whole. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67642758/45375) for more information.

- To intentionally terminate the entire call stack, use a [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw) statement (which can still be *caught* by a caller, however).
- To exit the *current script*, use `exit` (optionally with an exit code); to unconditionally return from a *function*, use [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Return).

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell has two fundamental error types: *non-terminating* ones are those occurring for individual input objects and don't prevent the command from processing other inputs, and *terminating* ones, which are those that cause the command to instantly terminate, and - situationally - execution overall. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375) for more information.</sup>