# GitLab CI: allow_failure:exit_codes does not behave as expected with powershell

Tags: powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Using a shell executor with powershell, allow_failure:exit_codes do not behave as documented
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failureexit_codes

With the following very simple job:

```
build:
    script:
        - exit 4
    allow_failure:
      exit_codes:
        - 4
```

The job fails instead of passing with a warning sign.

It works perfectly with bash.
it works perfectly with `allow_failure: true`.

Am I missing something ? Is there a work around ?

Comment: This is probably a facet of how Powershell works, in general. See [returning an exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200325/returning-an-exit-code-from-a-powershell-script). [This issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/28244) suggests that using `"$host.SetShouldExit($code); exit $code"` is a workaround. Could you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an aspect of how Powershell works, in general. See: [Returning an exit code from a PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200325/returning-an-exit-code-from-a-powershell-script)

To workaround this for a shell executor running powershell, use the following:

```yaml
script:
  - $host.SetShouldExit(4); exit 4
# ...
```

Note, however this workaround may not work for *custom* executors, like the beta `shared-windows` autoscaling executors on gitlab.com -- there is no workaround in that case at this time of writing.

Comment: Work around works great, thanks.